# Opensource Auto scaling for HiveMQ Broker

Tags: mqtt, haproxy, broker, hivemq

I am trying to configure Highly scalable HiveMQ broker(commercial edition) on ubuntu. I have 3 servers: server A, server B and Server C.
On Server A Ha-proxy is configured For Load balancing.
On server B mosquito broker is configured.
On server C mosquito broker is configured.
Server B and C have subscribed to HA proxy (server A).

My concern is that when the messages coming from client got high at some point a single broker can not handle that many messages at a time.

I just want when client publishes message higher than the limit then one more hiveMq broker gets started by itself and work as the other node. the same message should not be written on both brokers. like Auto-scaling in AWS.

Comment: Your question is not clear need more details to understand pls read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @AjayPandya edited you can ask if there is some part missing u want to know about.

Comment: What research have you already done and what have you tried?

Comment: I tried to change haproxy.conf file, here is changed parameters     "# Listen to all MQTT requests (port 1883)
listen mqtt
  # MQTT binding to port 1883
  bind *:1883
  # communication mode (MQTT works on top of TCP)
  mode tcp
  option tcplog
  # balance mode (to choose which MQTT server to use)
  balance leastconn
  # MQTT server 1
  server mosca_1 178.62.122.204:1883 check
  # MQTT server 2
  server mosca_2 178.62.104.172:1883 check"

Comment: when I am senging request to ha proxy message is coming to only one machine